# Rascal: Doesn't Find JDK on Windows commandline

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to run Rascal on Windows from the command line, with the command given on the [webpage](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/start/), but I get this exception:

```
$ java -Xmx1G -Xss32m -jar rascal-0.18.2.jar
Version: 0.18.2
INFO: detected |lib://rascal| at |jar+file:///D:/workspace/mach/delphi2java/lib/rascal-0.18.2.jar!/|


unexpected error: Unexpected error in Rascal interpreter: Could not find an installed System Java Compiler, please provide a Java Runtime that includes the Java Development Tools (JDK 1.6 or higher).
org.rascalmpl.interpreter.asserts.ImplementationError: Unexpected error in Rascal interpreter: Could not find an installed System Java Compiler, please provide a Java Runtime that includes the Java Development Tools (JDK 1.6 or higher).
        at org.rascalmpl.interpreter.utils.JavaBridge.<init>(JavaBridge.java:92)
        at org.rascalmpl.interpreter.Evaluator.<init>(Evaluator.java:215)
        at org.rascalmpl.interpreter.Evaluator.<init>(Evaluator.java:202)
        at org.rascalmpl.shell.ShellEvaluatorFactory.getDefaultEvaluator(ShellEvaluatorFactory.java:33)
        at org.rascalmpl.shell.REPLRunner$1.constructEvaluator(REPLRunner.java:45)
        at org.rascalmpl.repl.RascalInterpreterREPL.initialize(RascalInterpreterREPL.java:85)
        at org.rascalmpl.repl.BaseREPL.initialize(BaseREPL.java:153)
        at org.rascalmpl.repl.BaseREPL.<init>(BaseREPL.java:108)
        at org.rascalmpl.repl.BaseREPL.<init>(BaseREPL.java:62)
        at org.rascalmpl.shell.REPLRunner.<init>(REPLRunner.java:34)
        at org.rascalmpl.shell.RascalShell.main(RascalShell.java:91)
```

`javac` is in my PATH, and I have set JAVA_HOME to the JDK's root directory. What am I missing?

Comment: I was too quick answering and removed it. To which installation does the  `java` Command point? I don't know whether Windows has a `which` command but let's check if it's a JDK and not a JRE.

Comment: @JurgenVinju This was the decisive hint! My default `java` command comes from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`, while `javac` and `JAVA_HOME` point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\` (and `\bin` respectively). I need to explicitly start java with the binary from the JDK, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin\java.exe`. I'll add an answer to that end. Please add any comments or corrections.

Comment: Ok; thanks for adding the answer!

Comment: BTW: On Windows you can use the `where` command in place of `which`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I have both a JRE and a JDK on my machine, and the `java` command was found in the JRE first. I need to invoke Rascal with the `java` binary from the JDK, e.g. in my case call explicitly

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin\java" -Xmx1G -Xss32m -jar rascal-0.18.2.jar
```

Having `JAVA_HOME` set properly and `javac` in the path does not suffice.